# Connect android to webserver on beaglebone over bluetooth

Tags: linux, networking, bluetooth, beagleboneblack, bluez

I have a beaglebone black running debian 7.7 and it has a lighttpd server running. I have a few php pages which access a mysql database on the bbb. If I connect a wifi dongle on the bbb I can use my android phone browser to view the php pages using the wlan0 interface ip on the bbb. I want to do the same using a bluetooth dongle on the bbb. This is what I have done so far, I have setup a bridge on the bbb, I start a NAP server, I use my android phone to pair and connect with the bbb (wifi disabled on the android so I can use internet from the bbb, this just lets me connect to the NAP server). After this I have a bridge with eth0 and bnep0 interfaces. I try to use my browser to access the static ip I have set for the bridge but I dont get anything (also no tcpdump data on the bridge). I have ip4 forwarding enabled. My code follows,

[/etc/network/interfaces]

```
auto eth0
    iface eth0 inet manual

auto br1
    iface br1 inet static
    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_fd 9
    bridge_hello 2
    bridge_maxage 12
    bridge_stp off
    address 192.168.1.20
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.1.255
    gateway 192.168.1.1

iface usb0 inet static
    address 192.168.7.2
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.7.0
    gateway 192.168.7.1
```

[create nap server code]

```
1 #!/usr/bin/python
2
3 import sys
4 import time
5 import dbus
6 from optparse import OptionParser, make_option
7
8 bus = dbus.SystemBus()
9
10 manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", "/"),
11             "org.bluez.Manager")
12
13 option_list = [
14     make_option("-i", "--device", action="store",
15         type="string", dest="dev_id"),
16     ]
17 parser = OptionParser(option_list=option_list)
18
19 (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
20
21 if options.dev_id:
22   adapter_path = manager.FindAdapter(options.dev_id)
23 else:
24   adapter_path = manager.DefaultAdapter()
25
26 server = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object("org.bluez", adapter_path),
27             "org.bluez.NetworkServer")
28
29 service = "nap"
30
31 if (len(args) < 1):
32   bridge = "tether"
33 else:
34   bridge = args[0]
35
36 server.Register(service, bridge)
37
38 print "Server for %s registered for %s" % (service, bridge)
39
40 print "Press CTRL-C to disconnect"
41
42 try:
43   time.sleep(1000)
44   print "Terminating connection"
45 except:
46   pass
47
48 server.Unregister(service)
```

[pand -l]

```
   bnep0 18:A9:F0:90:D3:20 NAP
```

[brctl show br1]

```
   bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
   br1             8000.001986003430       no              bnep0
                                                           eth0
```

[EDIT]

Another thing I noticed after getting the android device on the bridge was the state of eth0 after using an ip link command,

```
   eth0 NO-CARRIER and DOWN
```

I am not sure if the webserver needs this interface or wlan0 to be up.

Any suggestions would be helpful.